# Debugging http.get and observables in angular 2

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-http

I have been trying to get the REST API from Ensemble running on
Angular2 using observables. I am not sure what the problem is with it.
This is how my code looks like (and the error is attached here http://pastebin.com/mSHEq43H)

Notice that I have added proper headers. To verify, we can change the
header value and see that we receive a 415 if I change the header
name.

---

```
    let header = new Headers();
    header.append('Content-type', 'application/json');
    this.http.get('http://rest.ensembl.org/lookup/id/ENSG00000157764?expand=0',
{
      headers: header
    })
      .map((res: Response) => res.json())
      .subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log('data');
        this.data = data;
      },
      error => {
        this.errorMessage = <any>error;
      },
      () => console.log('random look complete'));
```

---

I have also tried my API with only the Content-type header set as
application/json on Postman it works without any issue using the same
ID and header.

In order to debug further, I used an alternate API  which works fine

---

```
   this.http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos/1')
    .map((res: Response) => res.json())
        .subscribe(res => {
            this.data = res;
            this.errorMessage = false;
        });
```

---

Am I missing out on anything?

Other questions that I have is if there is an easy way to debug observabless as well? Any resource will be helpful.

---

Update

I have figured out what the problem is
Angular 2 on RC5 ( I have not checked with the final release yet).
http.get API has two parameters (url, RequestOptionsArg).

If I am using RequestOptionsArg, then I have to pass in ALL the parameters even the body if it was empty.

The documentation says if the body is empty it will be assigned null or undefined. However, the API calls toString() and I am assuming there are no checks for null and hence the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Well it looks like the error is:

```
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of null
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of null
    at Request.Body.text (http://172.17.110.205:3000/vendor.bundle.js:47211:26)
    at Request.getBody (http://172.17.110.205:3000/vendor.bundle.js:49014:29)
    at Observable._subscribe (http://172.17.110.205:3000/vendor.bundle.js:46832:37)
    at Observable.subscribe (http://172.17.110.205:3000/vendor.bundle.js:87952:62)
    at Observable._subscribe (http://172.17.110.205:3000/vendor.bundle.js:88009:28)
    at MapOperator.call (http://172.17.110.205:3000/vendor.bundle.js:90202:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (http://172.17.110.205:3000/vendor.bundle.js:87952:38)
    at SearchComponent.onSubmit (http://172.17.110.205:3000/0.chunk.js:37:14)
    at DebugAppView._View_SearchComponent2._handle_click_14_0 (SearchComponent.ngfactory.js:730:35)
```

So does the request return any body? Your code looks fine, so the problem is probably somewhere else. Is the above code coming from `SearchComponent`?

Regarding debugging `rxjs` code, you can definitely Google some interesting articles, however usually the only options is using do() operator to see what data's going through the operator chain.

Notable pages:

- [A tool to visualize Observable chains](https://react.rocks/example/rxvision) - see  [demo](http://jaredforsyth.com/rxvision/examples/playground/)
- [Marble diagrams interactive demo](http://rxmarbles.com/#skip)
- https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/testing.md
- http://staltz.com/how-to-debug-rxjs-code.html